# C# SQLite DB fails to open with file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I have a C# project which is editing an existing SQLiteDB from another product (not one I am in control of), my problem is that when trying to open the DB in code I receive the following exception:
"File opened that is not a database file, file is encrypted or is not a database"

So my assumption is that the DB is encrypted and I will not be able to edit it! However I used SQLite DB Browser and the DB opens with no issues and does not request a password etc.

I then used SQLite DB Browser to Encrypt the DB and left the password blank after doing this I am now able to connect to the DB in code, my problem is everytime this third party application accesses it's DB it is doing something to it as I then cannot open it in code again until I redo the step above.

Does any have any clue as to what can cause this behaviour I have included a snippit of my code below:

```
            // Build the connection string.
            lstrFullConnectionString = @"Data Source =" + lstrDBPathAndFileName + "; Version=" + lstrDBVersion + "; New=" + lstrDBNew + ";";
        mobjSQLCon = new SQLiteConnection(lstrFullConnectionString);

        try
        {// Fails at connection open....
            mobjSQLCon.Open();
            lblConnectionStatus.Text = "Status: Connected";
            btnSQLiteConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
        }
```

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Comment: `my assumption is that the DB is encrypted` dont assume,  find out.  After the other app uses it, go to the file and open it with a Hex viewer or even NotePad if it is not too large.  If it is encrypted, it will look like chinese characters.

Comment: Hi Plutonix, Thanks for you response I have opened the DB using a Hex Editor plugin within NotePad++ and I am able to see the information i.e unencrypted. I then tried using just Notepad ++ to view the text and the differences between Contracts.db and Contracts-SetBlankEncyption.db and there are noticable differences in content but again both readable. What I mean by blank encyption is using the SQLite DB Browser to remove the encryption by setting a blank password.

Comment: If you can see recognizable data, its not encrypted. The exception will be thrown when you try to use a db which is NOT encrypted but you have a PW in the conn str

Comment: Ahhh okay excellent thank you I dont know how the DB Browser is managing to get around the password! I will investigate further I have the Source Code for DB Browser since it's Open Source I can take a look. Thanks again, 
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue after help from Plutonix and further investigation I have found the following: When opening the DB in a Hex Viewer the first few header lines were different from the one I couldnt open in code and the one I could open (after opening with SQLite DB Browsers and removing the "encryption" I use it like that as the file was not actually encyrpted.

So the solution was to edit the file at a binary level to change the header to match and now I can open the DB. An example of the code I used to change the file was the following:

```
using (var lobjFileStream = new FileStream(pstrSQLiteDBPathAndFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                lobjFileStream.Position = 19;
                lobjFileStream.WriteByte(0x01);
            }
```

Thanks,
Luke